# maximum number of cycles in a directed graph with verices=|V| and edges =|E|

Tags: math, time-complexity, depth-first-search

Respected Sir,

I am working with a specific graphical structure representing 2-player normal form games (game theory). I know that I can compute all strongly connected components of the directed graph in O(V+E) via Tarjans, but was wondering what the complexity of computing all of the simple cycles of a strongly connected component is? AND, if there is a known upper bound on the number of such simple cycles given the number of vertices defining the strongly connected component?

I am looking for any literature/algorithms related to both of these problems. THANK YOU!

Comment: In a fully connected digraph (E=V²), pretty much everything induces a cycle, so it's superpolynomial. Is there more structure that can be exploited?

Comment: sir,i am having 'm+n' verices where 'n' is the number of processes and 'm' is number of resources.The Relation can be from Process to Resource or from a resource to Process..so total number of edges maximum is m*n.and its is purely directed graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the number of possible simple 2k-cycles are `(n choose k) * (m choose k)`.  If n, m, and k are not small, this grows exponentially.

Enumerating the cycles is not feasible.  I doubt that it is possible to count them for an arbitrary graph in reasonable time.  Even with dynamic programming techniques this takes exponential time and space (but with a lower exponent than without those techniques).